# how to set Graph request header to return Outlook tasks body in plain text

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get the response from `/beta/me/outlook/tasks` to return the body as raw `text` (`"body": {"contentType": "text",}`), but I'm always receive it in `html` format.

```js
async getTaskList(): Promise<TaskList[]> {
    try {
        let result = await this.graphClient
            .api('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks')
            .header("Prefer", "ContentType:'text'")
            //.header('Prefer', 'contentType="text"')
            .header('Prefer', 'outlook.timezone="central Europe Standard Time"')
            .header('IdType', 'ImmutableId')
            .select('id, owner, startDateTime, dueDateTime, subject, body')
            .filter("status ne 'completed' and startswith(subject,'Schválit home office')")
            .get();

        return result.value;
    } catch (error) {
        this.alertsService.add('Could not get tasks list', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    }
}
```

expected result:

```
"body": {
      "contentType": "text",
      "content": "Lorem ipsum ..."
    },
```

actual result:

```
"body": {
      "contentType": "html",
      "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from rtf -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font face=\"Calibri\" size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\">\r\n<div>Lorem ipsum ...</div>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n</span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    },
```

Comment: contentType is what you send, responseType is what you receive

Comment: I think you need to set the "Accept" http header

Comment: responseType: 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Outlook/Exchange endpoints, the correct syntax for the `Prefer` header is `outlook.body-content-type="text"`:

```js
   .header("Prefer", "utlook.body-content-type='text'")
```

That said, [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlooktask?view=graph-rest-beta), `/outlook/tasks` only supports requesting a preferred time zone and not the content-type. As such, you'll need to do the HTML to Text conversion on your end at the moment.

Given that it is still in beta/preview, this may change before it is released. There is a feedback section at the bottom of the documentation page where you could ask about their plans (or lack thereof) for adding this.